# Sharing audio over an IP network

Tags: windows-7, networking, audio

I have 2 seperate computers, A and B, both run on Windows 7, connected by a network.
My headphones are plugged to computer A.
I want to hear the audio from computer B on computer A.
Is there software that can do that for me?

I did find a few things that **might** work. The setup just seems a little messy. So if somebody has a solution that works I will be indebted.

Comment: Are you talking about a live streaming of audio? For example, you have a media center computer that is playing a movie. Your wife is on the couch next to you trying to sleep and you are on your laptop. Are you trying to essentially watch a movie on the media center computer/big screen and use the headphones plugged into your laptop for the audio?

Comment: you need to be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish.  What do you mean be share audio?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, its very easy. Turn on HomeGroup on computer B and add computer B in same HomeGroup. Then, in HomeGroup settings of computer B, share music library & allow media streaming..
Now, all you need is to use Windows Media Player on computer A.. Done!

**Update:**
Looks like you want to get all audio stream passing thru sound card of computer B. If you really want to listen empty recycle bin sound etc. too, first make sure your sound card of computer B supports audio master out or not. Then, use [IceCast](http://www.icecast.org/) to stream over network. In source, provide master out of computer B sound card.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to share anything you hear from one computer over ip you can use Stream What You Hear.

stream what you hear installed on one pc and Foobar2000 + Plugin UPnP on the other. A small delay but works well.

```
Capture any sound on your computer (“what you hear”)
Streaming as MP3 or WAV/PCM (L16) over HTTP
UPnP/DLNA 1.0 Media Server compliant
Supports automatic UPnP/DLNA Media Renderer detection and “Play” action
Record What You Hear into MP3 file
```

http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/features/